# Finding the value of Recursive Ackermann Function

Tags: c++, recursion

What is wrong in my code? It doesn't return the correct answer,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int ack(int m, int n)
{
    if (m == 0) return n + 1;

    if(n == 0) return ack(m - 1, 1);

    return ack(m - 1, ack(m, n - 1));

}

int main()
{
    cout << ack(4, 1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow - your recursion goes too deep I would guess.

Comment: I believe so but someone was able to find the value in his computer with the same program, I'm wondering is there anything with my ide setup, I'm using code::blocks. Machine has 8GB ram. @Ted Lyngmo

Comment: I think that you _may_ be successful if you compile with max optimization turned on so that you get tail recursion in the assembly code. Is the answer supposed to be 65533?

Comment: I rewrote it [without recursion](https://godbolt.org/z/rEGfq5). It becomes a bit slow but shouldn't crash. It's too slow to run on godbolt so you'll have to try it on your machine. Be sure you turn on max optimization.

Comment: I solved it with a combination of recursion and some memorization. But curious why it is not working in my computer. Basically I work on java -eclipse, do not know a lot about code::blocks. Thanks.

Comment: I would guess that it doesn't optimize the code well so that it actually does deep recursion and your stack can't handle it. Did you try with max optimization?

Comment: Where to set optimization, please?

Comment: No idea. I've never used Code::Blocks. `-O3` is common if you have a `gcc` or `clang` based compiler. I would however not trust optimization to solve this since it may not be able to handle all inputs you throw at the function. If the values are known at compile time it may be very successful, but not if the values are given at runtime.

Comment: It works, Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Memoize it!! That will make it both faster and use less memory
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753979/c-memoization-understanding

Comment: Yeah, I knew that, but I am interested for recursion. @Jeffrey.

Comment: You can use memoization and recursion at the same time.

Comment: How to add compiler flags on Code::Blocks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208733/how-to-add-compiler-flags-on-codeblocks

Answer (score 1):

Compiling it with a **C** compiler, instead of **C++**, your `ack()` function returned correctly, 65533, for me in about 20 seconds.

Using a recursive algorithm from [RosettaCode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Eliminating_Tail_Calls) that isn't *doubly* recursive like yours, returns the correct value in about 10 seconds:

```
int ack(int m, int n)
{
    for (; m > 0; m--) {
        n = (n == 0) ? 1 : ack(m, n - 1);
    }

    return n + 1;
}
```

Since you're not going to reach *higher* Ackermann values with this code, I don't see the point in going much *faster*.